# Translate breadcrumbs in checkout pages

Tags: i18n-l10n, breadcrumbs, commerce

I have a multilingual website. The breadcrumbs are also multilingual and that works fine. However, I am somehow not able to get the breadcrumbs of the checkout pages translated too. The checkout pages themselves are translated, but I don't see that in the breadcrumbs. I have tried string overrides, but that didn't work either.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?